# Adding Additional Hallo.js formatting features to Wagtail CMS RichTextField

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

How can I enable `halloformat underline` and `hallojustify` in Wagtails RichTextEditor? There doesn't seem to be any [documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#rich-text-features) on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process for defining new rich text features is documented immediately below the section you linked to:
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#extending-the-wysiwyg-editor-hallo-js

I would strongly recommend NOT enabling underline and justification options, though... Wagtail leaves them out for good reason. On the web, underline indicates a link - using underline for other things will look ugly and annoy your users.

Justification is a design choice, and design should be handled within the HTML and CSS, not by editors within the CMS. Editors should be dealing with the information content, not the presentation.

Comment: I appreciate and agree with your assessment, but there are certain things that I cannot get around, no matter how much I plead with them - the client wants underline :) . Thank you.